# How to add a custom NumPy function to the original source code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

To get a feel for [NumPy's](https://github.com/numpy/numpy) source code I want to start by adding my own dummy custom function. I've followed their [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/dev/development_environment.html#testing-builds) to set up a developing environment and have done an inplace build of NumPy as advised (`$ python setup.py build_ext -i; export PYTHONPATH=$PWD`).

Now I want to add this function:

```
def multiplybytwo(x):
    """
    Return the double of the input
    """

    y = x*2

    return y
```

But I do not know where to place it so that this code would run properly:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([10])

b = np.mulitplybytwo(a)
```

Comment: A starting point (of many) would be the top level `__init__.py` file in the numpy library.  Crack this open and read through the various imports and initialising setup.  This will help determine where the new function could be placed, as you’ll likely see from where other top-level functions are imported.

Comment: not sure I understand - do you want to add your function to Numpy lib (to Numpy library)?

Comment: @xhudik yes, that is my intent.

Comment: fork the project on github and maintain your own modified version.

Comment: ... while I’d generally discourage adding custom functionality to a library (as all changes will be lost on upgrade), I understand *why* you’re looking into this.  Just keep in mind what is stated in previous sentence.

Comment: @forgetso I have already done so

Comment: @S3DEV I've forked it and checked out a new branch just to get a feel for the source code. If I want to add my own custom function permanently, I'll open a PR

Comment: @S3DEV, so that worked out perfectly (of course it isn't the "right way" to do it but I can pick it up from there). If you write that as your answer I will accept it.

Comment: All done.  Cheers mate.  All the best in the familiarisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer has been added at OP’s request.

As mentioned in my comments above, a starting point (of many) would be to investigate the top level `__init__.py` file in the numpy library. Crack this open and read through the various imports and initialising setup. This will help to get your bearings as to where the new function could be placed, as you’ll likely see from where other (familiar) top-level functions are imported.

Caveat:
While I’d generally discourage adding custom functionality to a library (as all changes will be lost on upgrade), I understand *why* you’re looking into this. Just keep in mind what is stated in previous sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Everything in Python is an object!

So, you can add your function to NumPy in the same way you say that `x = 1`

See below:

```
>>> def multiplybytwo(x):
...     """
...     Return the double of the input
...     """
...     y = x*2
...     return y
```

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> np.mulitplybytwo = multiplybytwo   ## HERE IS THE "TRICK"

>>> a = np.array([10])

>>> b = np.mulitplybytwo(a)

>>> b
array([20])

>>> print(b)
[20]
```

In that line, you are creating a custom function in NumPy and saying that that function is the one defined by you.

You can have a proof using `id`

```
>>> id(np.multiplybytwo)
140489045965856

>>> id(multiplybytwo)
140489045965856
>>>
```

Both `id` are the same.

Comment: I guess that would be the trivial way to do it, but I'm looking to add it to the actual source code available on www.github.com/numpy/numpy

Answer (score 1):

if you want to add your function to Numpy, I'd:

1. clone github repo `git clone https://github.com/numpy/numpy.git`
2. write your function somewhere in `/numpy/core`
3. compile it: `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` -- more info about compilation/installation: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/building.html
4. for a deeper feel of Numpy - check how to contribute: https://numpy.org/devdocs/dev/index.html